# Random string primary key for table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I know there are many posts about this one, but there are a few things that none of them answered so far. Not here or on the Laracast forum.

**No.1**: What is the best practice to do this? I saw couple different ways of doing this. Should I set it in Model or in the Controller? Is there an automated way or it's just PHP `str_random(6)` function?

**No.2**: How to approach the possibility that the newly generated key could be a duplicate? Do I have to check it manually? I know that Laravel will throw the crap error if you tried to enter a duplicate in DB and I don't want that kind of an error on the live application.

**No3**: Will it slow down the application speed? My guess is if it has to check for duplicates, if the DB is large, it would be slow.

**No.4**: Should this even be done? I want to give this key to customers on the site, as their transaction key, for example. I don't want to know them how may of transactions there were before their one or give them any info regarding that. Security reasons.

I could guess answers, but I'm not 100% sure. If anyone has done this, I would appreciate any answers.

Comment: As a suggestion, you could use UUIDs instead ([related article](https://medium.com/@steveazz/setting-up-uuids-in-laravel-5-552412db2088))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use an integer primary key and add a separate column for the string key (with an unique index). Integer keys are faster and easier to handle (on joins etc.).

If the string key has a fixed length, you should use a `CHAR` column to get the best performance.

I would put the key generation into the controller:

```
$key = str_random(6);
while(YourModel::where('key', $key)->exists()) {
    $key = str_random(6);
}
$yourModel->key = $key;
```

Or you just try a key and catch the unlikely case of a duplicate value:

```
$yourModel->key = str_random(6);
try {
    $yourModel->save();
catch(Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
    <code from above>
    $yourModel->save();  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**No.1** : You can use `uniqid()` it will generate a unique identifier based on the current time in microseconds, you can do this just to make sure it's unique `$id = uniqid().str_random(5);`

**No.2** : using the above answer it's almost impossible to get duplicate keys but you can do this to 100% avoid it

```
try {
   $model->id = uniqid().str_random(5);
   $model->save();
}catch(\Exception $e)
{
 if something wrong happens try again or you can make it recrussive until it's able to save a unique key
}
```

**No.3** : i guess so

**No.4** : i don't recommend it, create another column which is also unique but it's something you give to users but it's not the primary key.
so this way, you can give each client/user a unique key so you can get his data later using it while still using auto increment as a primary key for other operations.

**Good luck**

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's good design to generate random strings as primary keys.

If you want to "hide" your transaction ids you could just hash/obfuscate your table key with [vinkla/laravel-hashids](https://github.com/vinkla/laravel-hashids).

Cool link: [easy-id-obfuscation-with-laravel-5](https://jenssegers.com/64/easy-id-obfuscation-with-laravel-5)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Jonas Staudenmeir that you should not use this as a primary key. You're not doing the DB any favours if you do this. Instead, treat it like regular application data; specifically, it sounds like a slug.

If you're building a tool to generate this key, then you can validate it like any other column to ensure it is unique.